# std::cin really slow

Tags: c++, pipeline, cout, cin

So I was trying to write myself a command for a linux pipeline. Think of it as a replica of gnu 'cat' or 'sed', that takes input from stdin, does some processing and writes to stdout.

I originally wrote an AWK script but wanted more performance so I used the following c++ code:

```
std::string crtLine;
crtLine.reserve(1000);
while (true)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, crtLine);
    if (!std::cin) // failbit (EOF immediately found) or badbit (I/O error)
        break;

    std::cout << crtLine << "\n";
}
```

This is exactly what cat (without any parameters does).
As it turns out, this program is about as slow as its awk counterpart, and nowhere near as fast as cat.

Testing on a 1GB file:

```
$time cat 'file' | cat | wc -l
real    0m0.771s

$time cat 'file' | filter-range.sh | wc -l
real    0m44.267s
```

Instead of getline(istream, string) I tried cin.getline(buffer, size) but no improvements. This is embarassing, is it a buffering issue? I also tried fetching 100KB at a time instead of just one line, no help! Any ideas?

EDIT:
What you folks say makes sense, BUT the culprit is not string building/copying and neither is scanning for newlines. (And neither is the size of the buffer). Take a look at these 2 programs:

```
char buf[200];
while (fgets(buf, 200, stdin))
    std::cout << buf;

$time cat 'file' | ./FilterRange > /dev/null
real    0m3.276s




char buf[200];
while (std::cin.getline(buf, 200))
    std::cout << buf << "\n";

$time cat 'file' | ./FilterRange > /dev/null
real    0m55.031s
```

Neither of them manipulate strings and both of them do newline scanning, however one is 17 times slower than the other. They differ only by the use of cin.
I think we can safely conclude that cin screws up the timing.

Comment: What else is in `filter-range.sh`? Why don't you invoke your C++ program directly? Also, the typical pattern for that loop is `while(std::getline(std::cin, crtLine)) { std::cout << crtLine << "\n"; }`, but changing that shouldn't affect your question.

Comment: If you are looking for performance, you should try C-style I/O functions instead of cin/cout ;)

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations? -O2 or -O3? That probably won't shave 44 seconds off, but if your worried about timing it should definitely be done.

Comment: Rob: Yes you're right, your version is equivalent and prettier. I used that, invoked the script directly, no change, and my program does nothing else. I'm using g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP

Comment: You are surprised that your general purpose command is slower than a specialized tool specifically designed to do something fast. If you wrote a command that beet cat then it would be the new cat. Since you are doing line processing I expect you to get (after heavy optimization on your part) about the same speed as any line based unix filter.

Comment: LihO: do you expect cin/cout to be responsible for 2-3 orders of magnitude slowdown compared to c-style I/O? Did you see the numbers?

Comment: To clarify on the "screw up" comment above: this particular implementation of I/O streams may screw some things up. I don't think it is required to screw things up and part of the problem is that you haven't really given it all the chances to optimize as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is exactly what cat (without any parameters does).

Not really. This has exactly the same effect as /bin/cat, but it does not use the same method.

`/bin/cat` looks more like this:

```
while( (readSize = read(inFd, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
  write(outFd, buffer, readSize);
```

Notice that `/bin/cat` does no processing on its input. It doesn't build a `std::string` out of it, it doesn't scan it for `\n`, it just does one system call after another.

Your program, on the other hand, builds `string`s, make copies of them, scans for `\n`, etc, etc.

This small, complete program runs 2-3 orders of magnitude slower than /bin/cat:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int ac, char **av) {
  std::string crtLine;
  crtLine.reserve(1000);
  while(std::getline(std::cin, crtLine)) {
    std::cout << crtLine << "\n";
  }
}
```

I timed it thus:

```
$ time ./x < inputFile > /dev/null
$ time /bin/cat < inputFile > /dev/null
```

---

**EDIT**
This program gets within 50% of the performance of /bin/cat:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main (int ac, char **av) {
  std::vector<char> v(4096);
  do {
    std::cin.read(&v[0], v.size());
    std::cout.write(&v[0], std::cin.gcount());
  } while(std::cin);
}
```

In short, if your requirement is to perform line-by-line analysis of the input, then you will have to pay some price to use formatted input. If, on the other hand, you need to perform byte-by-byte analysis, then you can use unformatted input and go faster.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, but also read the EDIT inside the original question

Answer (score 13):

The **first** thing you want to do to get good performance for the standard I/O stream objects it turn off synchronization with the standard C stream objects:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Once you have done this you should get much better performance. Whether you get good performance is a different question though.

Since some people claimed funny things about what `cat` would do inside, here is what is supposed to be the fastest approach to copy one stream to another:

```
std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
```

I would love if the you could properly `std::copy()` one stream to another but this won't work too well with most I/O stream implementations:

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

I hope I get to this being the best eventually...

Comment: Indeed, sync_with_stdio seems very helpful. It speeds things up 7-fold

Comment: Actually, this is gold, because it makes cin only 2 times slower than fgets, with the added benefit that you don't need to know max line length... any more 'optimizations' like this? :)

Comment: No, nothing as simple as this. Somewhere I have my own implementation of IOStreams which does quite a number of interesting optimizations but its incomplete state won't help you for now. I'm still hoping to get it up at some point, though... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really would like to have much better performance with stdin you should try to use pure C.

```
vector<char> line(0x1000);
while(!feof(stdin))
    fgets(&line.front(), line.size(), stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the faster solution will be based on [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile)