# Ofstream faster than cout? || Storage faster than visual ouput

Tags: c++, file-io, cout, ofstream

For whatever reason I decided to make a very simple application that displays all the numbers from 1-1,000,000. I noticed that it takes way longer to display the results than it does to store them. I assumed that it would take longer to store all the values than it would to display them. I also remember reading, if I remember right, that there isn't really any difference between user input and reading from a text file in a console application, so I assumed that display and storage are the same.
Can someone explain why this is? According to the book I'm reading ofstream is really similar to cout, so I dont' understand why it takes longer.

Why is it slower to display the results using `cout` than it is to store the results in a text file using `ofstream`?

**cout = 169.168 seconds**

**ofstream = 3.473 seconds**

*ofstream method*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace patch //used to patch some C++11 functions not included in mingw 4.7 // to_string
{
    template < typename T > std::string to_string( const T& n )
    {
        std::ostringstream stm ;
        stm << n ;
        return stm.str() ;
    }
}
using namespace patch;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int minimumRange = 1; //sets minimum number in range
    int maximumRange = 1000000; // sets maximum number in range
    string strRanges = to_string(minimumRange) + "-" + to_string(maximumRange); //appends string names
    ofstream myRange;
    myRange.open(strRanges + ".txt");

    for (int i = minimumRange; i<=maximumRange; ++i)
    {
        myRange << to_string(i) << "\n";
    }
   myRange.close();
    return 0;
}
```

*cout method*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int minimumRange = 1;
    int maximumRange = 1000000;
    for (int i = minimumRange; i<=maximumRange; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << "\n"; //using "/n" instead of endl; for speed purposes
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The console/terminal program itself is slow.

Comment: Maybe the system caches the file for you and writes the data asynchroneously to disk? This will be simple memory accesses for your file version. Writing to the console is bound by console speed (which can be quite slow)

Comment: D: ... why are you using ``stringstream``s to print ints. T_T my brain is hurting right now.

Comment: @Dieter What Dieter said. This is why you don't add the verbose flag when untarring files, because it's faster when there is no console output. Otherwise, it would be blazingly fast and subsequently the user can't read what's on the screen.

Comment: Just to prove a point, try doing this `./program > /dev/null` with the `std::cout` version.

Comment: @quasiverse I haven't used C++ in a few years since 8th grade. I'm getting started again and I'm a junior. I'm not as advanced as I should be if I didn't put C++ down. (Not sure why I did. I like it way better than web design.) Anyway, what method would you prefer? This is the only method that I know. Is there a better method? I'm looking at getting started with QT as soon as I finish C++ Primer.

Comment: @remyabel I'm using a Windows 7 PC right now. My Linux has a failing hard drive and a screen that won't work, so I can't use it right now. This is actually my mom's laptop (I'm still a high schooler, not a stay at home adult), and she doesn't want installing another OS on her laptop.

Comment: @Crysis Sorry, I wasn't saying you were bad. Far from it, hahah. Unless I horribly misread your code, you can just output ``int``s like you would with ``std::string``s (and also just like you output it with ``std::cout``). Perhaps it didn't sound that way but I was laughing at how you knew about ``stringstream``s, a relatively complex topic, and yet didn't realise you could just output the ``int`` straight out. :) If anything, you're too advanced ;).

Comment: @quasiverse I'd love to take credit for this, but I can't. I found the code after Googling for a while "why to_string(); wouldn't work with C++11 with GCC". 

I thought `ofstream` only took strings as arguments? That's what my book said. lol. I'll try straight up `ints`. Maybe that'll make the time 2.75 secs instead.

Comment: @quasiverse You were right. I just took out the string conversion and my program ran at .656 secs.

Comment: @Crysis Yeah, ``stringstream`` is pretty expensive time-wise. In fact, stringstreams and ``std::ofstream`` (and other streams) are all just related stream classes for different purposes. ``std::cout`` is just an object of type ``std::ofstream`` that points to the terminal and ``stringstream``s are just streams that input/output to strings in the same way ``ifstreams`` and ``ofstreams`` input/output to files. So by using your ``to_string()`` function, you're basically doing your file operations twice, as well as doing string operations. That's why it takes so long.

Comment: @quasiverse Makes sense. Is it possible to rewrite the `streams` in order to optimize them for speed? I've heard of a library named `Boost`, does it have a special class?

Comment: @Crysis To be honest, I haven't learnt so much Boost. But I'm pretty sure Boost is more about providing functionality that isn't in the standard C++ libraries. The things that are already in the C++ standard libraries (like I/O streams) are pretty much implemented really well already. Boost just adds more stuff that didn't make it into the standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026594/420683 <- Before measuring performance of `std::cout`, decouple it from the C Standard streams

Comment: @Ali `myRange.open(strRanges + ".txt");` is C++11 (using a `std::string` to open a file) -- only found that trying to compile it w/o `-std=c++11` ;)

Comment: @DyP OK, I have missed that tiny part. But still, the essence of the question has nothing to do with C++11. It is trivial to change `myRange.open(strRanges + ".txt");` so that it compiles under C++98 without changing the essence of the question or the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On many systems, `cout` is just a `ostream` instance mapping the `CON` file.

The point is that ostream doesn't write anything.

Its purpose is to convert whatever supported type (maninly: `const char*`, `std::string`, `int`, `long`..., `double` ...) into a "sequence of characters" to be placed in a buffer (see `std::streambuf`).

In this sense storing or typing does the same.

The difference arises when the buffer characters have to be spit out towards the *physical* device: That's where the device drivers and related physical problems (essentially: bandwidth, latency and interleaving) come into play.

When the OS trasnfer a bulk of data to a disk file, it uses a driver that may internally use caching that talks to an external device using a communication protocol (mainly SATA, SCSI, NFS...) that talks toward a controller (a microcomputer on the disk) tha also has its caching that later manipulates the magnetic storage.

Your program says "write", the OS tells "written" but data are still being worked out by device controllers outsite of the OS control. The "slow" part happens asyncronously  respect to you.

When you have to write to the console, most of this "caching" cannot be done: as soon you wait for an input, cout is flushed (you want to read what you wrote if it is a question you have to answer).

For this reason the console driver has to wait for the console program to complete its writing before proceed over. But it's writing is in fact a "painting": the characters have to be converted into pixels by means of fonts, and painting must be in sync with the display scanning (otherwise the image will be "disturbed").

This process is slower (an longer) than "writing to disk" that -in fact- translates into "move a bulk of memory from the process to an IO port" (and where the hardware can really do this by swapping two pointer registers)

Also, the console program is optimized for data to be seen (and makes no sense to make it faster than the eyes), while a disk driver is optimized for data to be transfered. It's quite normal for it to be faster.

Comment: This actually makes sense to me and it's 3 am here. I didn't think about the console practically painting the results, or the fact that it is optimized to see data, not show 1-1million at speeds a user can't comprehend. 

Is it possible to create an optimized console or GUI that is able to display these results in a more timely fashion? I'm just talking hypothetically, unless something like QT or wxWidgets is faster, though I assume a full blown GUI would be slower.

Comment: Well, if I know the receiving device is slow and the only important thing are the last sent data, and I can somehow predict when "last data" happen, I can avoid to print at all what will never be seen...  This may looks stange but... A full blown gui can be aware of that more easily than a simple console driver (that has to work even in recovery situation... so i must not b too complex). Depending on how the GUI had been optimized, it can happen it appers to be even more fast. ...  But is too much implementation specific, and cannot be discussed in general form anymore.