# How to make custom input cin-like function?

Tags: c++, function, input

While being simple to write, the downside of the `cin` function is slow when compared to others like `scanf` or `getchar`. Now, I have my own quick input function to replace, but are rather troublesome to write:

```
void read(signed long long &var){
    var = 0;
    
    register char neg = getchar(), c;
    
    while(neg != '-' and neg < '0' and neg > '9') // check negativity
        neg = getchar();
        
    if (neg == '-')
        c = getchar();
    else
        c = neg;
        
    while(c >= '0' and c <= '9' ){
        var = (var << 3) + (var << 1) + (c - '0');
        c = getchar();
    }
    if (neg == '-')
        var *= -1;
}
```

When I need to input some variable, I need to pass every single one of them into the `read` function, and I found it quite troublesome.

```
signed long long varA, varB, varC;
read(varA);
read(varB);
read(varC);
```

My question is, can I make a `cin-like` function that behaves like my `read` function? One that looks like this, maybe?

```
signed long long varA, varB, varC;
read >> varA >> varB >> varC;
```

Edit: `While` condition in `read` function

Comment: Don't discard `std::cin` immediately, it can be made much faster with things like [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).

Comment: Anyway your read function is plain wrong: `neg != '-' or neg < '0' or neg >= '9'` is always true... Did you try it?

Comment: the problem with your question is that `std::cin` isnt magic, it is implemented as part of standard libraries, hence the answer to your question taken literally is "Yes of course you can implement something that works similar to `std::cin`". Though explaining all details of how to implement it is too broad. You should rather investigate how to make using `std::cin` faster. The first comment is already a very good hint

Comment: You must first understand that `cin` is not a function; `>>` is a function.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes, sorry. I have edited the while condition and tested it to ensure it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While being simple to write, the downside of the cin function is slow when compared to others like scanf or getchar

Are you really sure? Did you benchmark it? And what are your requirements? C++ streams are very feature rich which comes at a cost...

> Now, I have my own quick input function to replace...

I did not benchmark it, but I will assume it to be fast. Anyway, `register` is deprecated since C++14 and was removed in C++17. But an input method that gladly accepts `abc12e-45-13` as input and returns 3 numbers 12, -45 and -13 is **very** tolerant. Up to you to make sure that it meets your needs.

> can I make a cin-like function that behaves like my read function? One that looks like this, maybe?
>
> ```
> signed long long varA, varB, varC;
> read >> varA >> varB >> varC;
> ```

You only have to build a custom class and implement an `operator >>` on it:

```
class LLReader {
    FILE* fd;      // the wrapped C FILE, by default stdin

public:
    LLReader(FILE* fd = stdin) : fd(fd) {}

    void read(signed long long& var) {
        var = 0;

        // BEWARE register is deprecated since C++14 and forbidden in C++17
        register char neg = getc(fd), c;
        
        // FIX here
        while (neg != '-' && (neg < '0' || neg >= '9')) // check negativity
            neg = getc(fd);

        if (neg == '-')
            c = getc(fd);
        else
            c = neg;

        while (c >= '0' && c < '9') {
            var = (var << 3) + (var << 1) + (c - '0');
            c = getc(fd);
        }
        if (neg == '-')
            var *= -1;
    }
};

LLReader& operator >> (LLReader& reader, long long& val) {
    reader.read(val);
    return reader;
}
```

You can now use:

```
signed long long varA, varB, varC;
LLReader read;

read >> varA >> varB >> varC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I've got what you trying to do, then just create class with your read function in it as a member and overload `operator >>`.

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm not sure you can overload `>>` for things that are not streams. It's an elegant approach, I'm just not sure it will work; and if it does, you should flesh out your Answer a little more.

Comment: @Beta I'm assuming that provided read function works. TS just asks for utility improvement on it, as far as I know. Implementation is rather simple given again that read function works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) (requires C++17)

```cpp
void read(signed long long &var);

template<typename ... T>
void readMany(T&... t) {
    ((void) read(t), ...);
}

int main() {
    signed long long a;
    signed long long b;
    readMany(a, b);
}
```

Comment: This is not required and OP's code is not compatible with C++17...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `read` is correct and working (actually I am not sure if it is, but I will concentrate on the specific question here), you are looking for a way to chain calls to it. There are different way to realize it.

First you need to understand that `std::cin` is not a function (what Beta said in a comment). It is a global object of type `std::istream` and there is a function like this (we consider only `signed long long`):

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& instream, signed long long& var);
```

When you call `std::cin >> x;` then the operator returns a reference to `std::cin` so you can chain calls like this:

```
std::cin >> x >> y;
```

We can mimick this by writing an `operator>>` that allows chaining, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

void read(signed long long &var){ var = 42; }

struct reader {
    reader& operator>>(signed long long& var) {
        read(var);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    signed long long var1,var2,var3;    
    reader{} >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;    
    std::cout << var1 << " " << var2 << " " << var3;   
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq4ofnfbz):

```
42 42 42
```

However, if you want `std::cin` to be faster, there are simpler ways to achieve it. There is a reason why `std::cin` is so slow. To allow mixing of C++ and C io, it has to be synchronized with C io streams. You can turn this off via `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`. See eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026594/4117728).